# How to use a demo save in the full game

Tags: football-manager-2013

I played the Football Manager 2013 Demo and now went to "games" folder and copied the save to the Full Game's "games" folder. But when I try to load it it says "The saved game could not be resumed". There's anything else I can do so I can play this save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saved game cannot be resumed because there are 'hooks' in the code which trigger the game to discontinue.

I used to work for Sports Interactive so the only possible way for this demo saved game to be continued is for a senior coder to have it converted into a full game save or have the hooks removed.

Even then, you will probably find that the database on your demo is too old a version and a new error will spawn.